# XML parser in swift 2 returns false on device

Tags: ios, xml, swift, nsxmlparser

When I run the following code in Xcode with iOS simulator selected it parses without a problem, but when I run it on a device (iPhone 5c) I get:
*Failed to load xml
XML parsing failed at 0:0: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)")*

I tried different xml files, but it looks like its a security issue!?
Should I set permission in my project somewhere?

```
let url:String="http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss#sthash.TyhRD7Zy.dpuf"
let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
parser.delegate = self

if !parser.parse() {
   let error = parser.parserError
   let line = parser.lineNumber
   let col = parser.columnNumber
   print("XML parsing failed at \(line):\(col): \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help isolate the error, it might be helpful to load the contents of the URL into a string first – that would help you isolate whether it's a security problem or a parsing problem. You might also want take away the force unwraps and use if/let so you can see the flow of errors more clearly.

That being said, here are some things to check:

1) Is the device online?

2) Is the device connected to a proxy, VPN or other intermediary that blocks some resources?

3) Is the device able to reach that URL when you use Safari?

4) Is your parser able to read other RSS feeds?

In my experience, 2) is often the problem.

Comment: @Walter: as this solved your problem, marking the answer as correct helps others identify the solution if they hit the same problem.